# Cognito - How to authenticate client in nodejs backend on a different subdomain than the one the client obtained the token from (through amplify)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an authentication flow going in https://mysite.co/auth/ which is implemented using Amplify (the app in https://mysite.co/ is based on Next.js)

When the user successfully authenticates he gets a Cognito token from Amplify and is then redirected to https://app.mysite.co/ (which is pure Javascript front-end with Node.js back-end)

How can I use the Cognito token obtained from https://mysite.co/auth/ for authenticating the user in https://app.mysite.co/?

I'm assuming this is possible, for example using the local storage, but don't have experience with authentication and am lost in finding good pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Im not sure if this is the best practice, bust storing the token in your Session Storage to use later might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch Cognito to use [cookie based auth](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js#scoped-configuration) and set your your domain to `mysite.co` without any paths or subdomin so it can be used across subdomains you own.

```
{
 cookieStorage: {
  domain: 'mysite.co'// 'localhost' for dev - no port
 }
}
```

*Cognito doesn't support secure cookie at this time - however, it doesn't make a difference because the only other supported method is local storage and the data is still accessible via JS.*

*If you set a lot of extra information in your JWTs you could hit a cookie size limit (4096 byte limit). Standard Cognito JWT is ~1800 bytes*

2. Imponent cross domain local storage on the client  to read the local storage for the other subdomain - not trivial and case specific. I don't know if this is possible with Cognito. [Here is an article](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/alternatives-to-third-party-cookies-in-2020-857609f8f2bb) that discusses using post message - this method is hacky.
3. Move your Auth service to be under app.mysite.co/auth.  Most JS frameworks like React allow you to have a separate instances under a specific path/route (/auth).

   `app.mysite.co` and all paths except `/auth` are app-`1`

   Path `app.mysite.co/auth` and all it's subpaths are app-`2` (auth)